# Change checkbox checked status based on $_GET parameters

Tags: php, ajax

I'm working on a project for a university to register the students. I'm using PHP and Ajax. I created a page to show every student data and there is a button to edit the registers (you can either update or delete one of the registers). One of the parameters that every student has is where he is either active or not. So, when you click at the edit button it sends this information via URL to the edit student page (edit.php?active=yes if the student is active or, edit.php?active=no if the student is not active).

The problem is the following: at this edit student page I have a checkbox that says "Active student" and I want it to be checked if the active=yes and not checked if active=no (maybe the admin just want to change the student's email and if this checkbox is in a different state, it will result in a wrongly activated or deactivated student.

I tried a lot of solutions but none seems to be working for me. Can you guys help me please?

Thanks in advance,

Alan

Comment: Alan- Put some code here that you tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would adjust Dialex answer to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="active" <?php if(isset($_GET['active']) && $_GET['active'] == 'yes') { echo 'checked'; } ?> > Active student
```

Answer (score 2):

With some research, you could have found the answer. You can just check if the GET variable is set, and with a condition, echo the `checked` propriety of the input.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="active" <?php if(isset($_GET['active'])){ echo 'checked'; } ?> > Active student
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a checkbox on a form, the name=value pair in the $_GET variable will only be defined if the checkbox was checked. If the checkbox is unchecked, then nothing is returned. So the correct PHP code to check for the value of a checkbox is:

```
if (isset($_GET['tagName'])) {
  // do some stuff here
}
```